# Nautilus script to decrypt

Tags: scripts, nautilus, pdf

I wrote this script to decrypt pdfs, in order to make them editable.

I want to decrypt them in their own folder, substituting the original ones.

```sh
directory=$(dirname "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
name='/out.pdf'
path=$directory$name

for line in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS; do    
    qpdf -decrypt $line $path
    mv $path $line
done
```

If I right-click only one file it works properly, instead if the selection is multiple nothing happens. What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Looks like you all write them to `out.pdf`.  try use `outfn=$(basename $line)` inside the for loop (`$outfn` is the filename without its path). Good luck!